# Dagster - running a cross repository job from a sensor

Tags: dagster

I've learned from the docs that a Dagster sensor could be triggered by a job from a different repo. In a similar manner, is there a way to run a cross repo job using the RunRequest inside the sensor, ie. something like this?

```
@run_status_sensor(
    run_status=DagsterRunStatus.SUCCESS,
    request_job=<job_from_a_different_repo>,
)
def my_sensor(context):
  return RunRequest(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, sensors can only submit runs for jobs that are defined in the same repository.

Here is a Github issue that tracks enabling sensors to submit runs for jobs that are defined in different repositories: https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/issues/10696.